# Создание правила для audgard

Tags: javascript, android, веб-дизайн, реклама

Как можно убрать навязчивую рекламу на версии для мобильных устройств без рута на стороне конкретного мобильного устройства?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя у меня и есть скрипт, убирающий рекламу на сайте:

```
<script>
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    div.innerHTML = '';
</script>
```

по правилам Ucoz этого делать нельзя.

Решил убрать её только для меня, на моём Android смартфоне, сделать правило на моей стороне, а не на хостинге. Нашел в интернете программу Audgard. Однако у меня не получается создать в ней собственные фильтры.

Можно ли как-нибудь заблокировать рекламу без рута?

Comment: поставьте себе "tor" браузер.

Comment: Нет , такое не очень подходит )